# magic_quotes_gpc vs stripslashes

Tags: php, pdo

I have two choices to store my html string:

1. turning off `magic_quotes_gpc` and store it directly using PDO.
2. turning on `magic_quotes_gpc` and let my html string be stored with slashes using PDO. then, convert those slashes by using the function `stripslashes();`

I need to know the pros and cons of those two choices, and which one do you recommend? I am guessing that there is a security threat with the first choice. and load on the server with the second choice, but I need to know what the experts say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Magic Quotes are deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). Don't use them. Use PDO and [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

As a side note you should not call to *experts* in this case. If the official PHP documentation says in a big red box *don't use this feature*, there is no question to be asked.

[image]

Comment: so from this.. there is no security threat If I disabled magic_quotes? I am running 5.3.9 and the magic quotes are ON!

Comment: @shnisaka `magic_quotes` have been deprecated because they give a false impression of security. You should not rely on this feature, and you will be safe **if** you use PDO or MySQLi extensions and prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is to use PDO like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname) VALUES (:firstname,:lastname)');
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Hope it helps.