# Why we should use the mysqli_real_escape_string() and the stripslashes() functions in a login and register php files

Tags: php

**1-** Why we should use the  `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and the `stripslashes()` functions in a register and login `php` files?

**2-** Does these functions change the contents of the fields? If the answer is yes as the result the contents of the fields such as the username will change and the next time if the user want to login with his/her username It can not, because the contents of the username has been changed already, for example at the time of the registering in a website and now and as the result it can not login to the website because the contents of the fields such as the username has been changed by the the  `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and the `stripslashes()` functions.

I have two ambiguity in the above questions.

Comment: [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

Comment: You shouldn't; you should be using prepared statements with bind variables if you're using MySQLi

Comment: The aim of the function `mysqli_real_escape_string` is to try to ensure that the data that is sent to the mysql server is safe - it attempts to remove characters that are often used in sql injection. `Stripslashes` again works in your favour in this respect as a common trick of those wishing to inject nastiness into your db will `escape` a character by using a slash - this removes those. If there are no suspicious characters in the string then it is unchanged.

Comment: If you pass a slashed string to stripslash() and a non-slashed one, they'll end up the same. It won't alter what you get, so your statement doesn't make much sense. Escaped strings are to prevent malicious inputs, but their returns are equal.

Comment: Related: [What is stripslashes for?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13853820) and [magic\_quotes\_gpc vs stripslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15346896)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using these functions makes your site less vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, where an attacker puts SQL syntax into a form field to compromise your site. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` "escapes" special characters so that MySQL interprets them as literal string characters rather than operators in the query.

These functions only affect characters that are important to SQL commands, and will not affect legitimate input, while foiling nefarious users.

Comment: There are ways to sidestep **real_escape_string** and it is by no means a magic-bullet answer. Same with **stripslashes**, it's a deprecated solution previous to real_escape_string and can be easily circumvented.